# UWP suspend operation on just one page

Tags: windows-runtime, win-universal-app, resume, suspend

As we all know that when we minimize the UWP app it goes to suspension. and then again when maximized it is exactly at the same place, for all pages. I want to do the same for specific pages, on my own. meaning that I want to do the same operation for one or more pages, when I switch between pages in my app, without minimizing? when app is minimized, even the videos playing on it pause automatically, and when maximized they play themselves, I want to achieve that functionality when I switch to next page and when I come back to previous page, it should start playing again, like it was suspended. thankyou in advance.

The app I am making plays a video on a url in a webview on a page, I want that when I come back to that page after navigating somewhere else on my app, that webview start playing exactly at the same place. Thats exactly wht happenes when I minimize my app. but i wanna do that without minimizing it.

Also I have tried cahcesize of my frame and set navigationmode of my page to enabled, that just saves the current state, and the media on my page keeps on playing when I navigate to another page, it should pause, but it keeps onplaying

Comment: I try the method that you said, I got the same result the media keep on playing. I think if the website of the media is write from you. You can get the play and stop method. If the website did not provide API to control the video, it seems there is no method to do it.

Comment: how can i get the play and stop method? the website is running within my webview, can you guide me how can i get play and stop method? for example how can i get it if youtube is open in my webview and the video is playing in it ?